# How do I use my own web form with the ngx_http_auth_basic_module?

Tags: nginx, http-basic-authentication

I want to capture the username and password with my own form and then use those values with the Nginx ngx_http_auth_basic_module,rather than having the default Nginx box that comes up, asking for username and password?  I know how to create the form, that is not part of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can solve your problem with ngx_http_auth_basic_module. I believe you need to use another module to achieve your desired result.

"ngx_http_auth_request_module" sounds like it would address your goals. It "allows authorization based on subrequest result". Here are some resources for it:

- [README file](http://mdounin.ru/hg/ngx_http_auth_request_module/file/a29d74804ff1/README)
- [Main repo page](http://mdounin.ru/hg/ngx_http_auth_request_module/)
- [Example scripts](http://mdounin.ru/hg/ngx_http_auth_request_module/file/tip/t)

For a more detailed discussion of the topic, I recommend trying the [Nginx mailing list](http://mailman.nginx.org/mailman/listinfo/nginx).